# Unable to access recordTypeInfo using getObjectInfo of lightning/uiObjectInfoApi API in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to retrieve recordTypeInfo, & create a map of RecordType name & RecordType Id, for a custom object using **getObjectInfo** adapter from **lightning/uiObjectInfoApi** API, based on this example
(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_object_info).

This component is added on **Lightning Record Page**.

I keep receiving **[Cannot read property 'data' of undefined]** error.
[image: Sample Error]

Below is my code:-

---

opptyapplicationlist.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-textarea value={recTypeMap} label="RecordType"></lightning-textarea>
</template>
```

---

opptyapplicationlist.js

```
import {LightningElement, track, wire, api} from 'lwc';
import {getObjectInfo} from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import APPLICATION_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Application__c';

export default class OpptyApplicationList extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track recTypeMap = this.getAppRecType();
    @wire(getObjectInfo, {objectApiName: APPLICATION_OBJECT}) objectInfo;

    getAppRecType() {
        const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
        return Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'SBV MasterClass');
    }
}
```

Is there something amiss in the example, or am I missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue:

> Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

is because you are trying to refer to a property even before it has been declared. In your current JS, you are referring to `objectInfo` even before it is available.

**Resolution**

Declare a JS function which should return the Record Type Id only when the component has been rendered. And then utilize that JS function in your HTML. So your JS looks like:

```
// remove declaration of @track recTypeMap; this is not required at all 

@wire(getObjectInfo, {objectApiName: APPLICATION_OBJECT}) objectInfo;

// this is a getter function now, see get keyword
get getAppRecType() {
    const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
    return Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'SBV MasterClass');
}
```

Now, in HTML, make sure to verify for `objectInfo.data` before calling the function as the `data` will be available only when the component has finished rendering.

```
<div if:true={objectInfo.data}>
    {getAppRecType}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a get function to set your textarea. Change your javascript to something like this.

```javascript
export default class OpptyApplicationList extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track recTypeMap;
    @wire(getObjectInfo, {objectApiName: APPLICATION_OBJECT}) 
    objectInfo({error, data}){
        if(data){
            const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
            this.recTypeMap = Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'SBV MasterClass'); 
        }
    }

    get appRecType() {
        return this.recTypeMap;
    }
}
```

```
<template>
    <lightning-textarea value={appRecType} label="RecordType"></lightning-textarea>
</template>
```